# Casting between interfaces

Tags: java, interface, casting

My question is related to Java language.
This is what I got:

```
interface I1{}
interface I2{}
class C1 implements I1{}
class C3 extends C1 implements I2{}
```

When

```
     C1 01;
     C3 o3;
     I1 i1;
```

etc

And now it turns out that `I2 i2 = (I2) i1;` is right because at run time i1 actually refers to an object that implements I2.
 But I don't get it. Interfaces have no relationships between one another, so how can you cast it to an adjacent interface?
There is no more code, it is simply a drill in order to prepare for Java certification.
Best regards

Comment: In your code, even though the interfaces do not have any direct relationship between them, they do have a relationship between each other via the classes that implement them.

Comment: Where is `i1` variable declared?

Comment: Please post the declaration of the i1 variable. A complete code fragment would be even more useful.

Comment: @techfoobar That relationship is irrelevant if you are trying to cast an expr of type I1 to I2. The runtime value type doesn't enter the equation here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I2 i2 = (I2) i1;` means: I know that the concrete runtime type of the object referenced by `i1` implements the `I2` interface, so I would like to reference it as an `I2`. If the concrete runtime type of `i1` indeed implements `I2`, the cast will succeed.

The fact that `I1` and `I2` have nothing in common doesn't matter. What matters is the actual concrete runtime type of the object referenced by `i1`.

Answer (score 4):

If you cast an `Integer` to a `String`, the compiler can stop that as illegal, but, since a class can implement a variety of interfaces, the compiler can't know if you are trangressing when you cast one interface type to another. Consider this code:

```
I1 i1 = getI1();
if (i1 instanceof I2) {
  I2 i2 = (I2) i1;
}
```

If the Java compiler didn't allow casts from one interface to another, this perfectly legitimate piece of code wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You answered the question yourself ;-)

```
"[... ]is right because at run time i1 actually refers to an object that implements I2"
```

Typecasts are evaluated at runtime and not at compiletime. So if the object that `i1` points to at runtime is of type `I2` there are no errors.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, an interface is a type, like a bird - not an eagle or a duck.
Take concrete implementations of these classes (this is rather silly, but bear with me)

```
interface Bird {fly();}
interface Swimmer {swim();}
class Eagle implements Bird {fly(){...};}
class Duck extends Eagle implements Swimmer {swim(){...};}

Swimmer i2 = (Swimmer) i1;
```

This means that your code believes that i1 is an entity that can swim. If i1 is a Duck, this code will work, if it's an eagle, this will fail. The type casting is done at runtime not compile time.

Comment: Classes declare types too, not only interfaces.

Comment: True - I was trying to over-simplify (and work a swimming duck into the answer). The question looks like it has already been answered.